# Llamar secuencia en un create table almacenado en una variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigger, pgadmin

Hola tenga la siguiente problemática: He creado una secuencia en un trigger, para luego instanciarla dinámicamente por sentencias create de tablas en el mismo trigger. Cuando intento poner `NEXTVAL('secuencia')` las comillas simples me comentarean la variable, que puedo hacer en este caso pues son necesarias para poder llamar a la secuencia:

Secuencia

```
sql := 'CREATE SEQUENCE mod_riestadistica.sec_'||nombretabla||'_seq
          INCREMENT 1
          MINVALUE 1
          MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
          START 1
          CACHE 1;
          ALTER TABLE public.sec_'||nombretabla||'
          OWNER TO postgres;';
          execute sql;

sql := 'CREATE TABLE public.t_'||nombretabla||'('||nombre_id||' numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL ("public"."sec_' || nombretabla||'"), CONSTRAINT pk_' ||nombretabla||' PRIMARY KEY ('||nombre_id||' ) )
          WITH ( OIDS=FALSE); ALTER TABLE public.t_'||nombretabla||' OWNER TO postgres;';

execute sql;
```

Comment: debes poner en vez de una comilla, 2 comillas de cada lado, asi te va a funcionar, y si no 3 comillas de cada lado, pero estoy seguro que con 2 comillas te funciona.

Answer (score 0):

En tu pregunta hay una contradicción, porque

- creas la **secuencia** `mod_riestadistica.sec_'||nombretabla||'_seq`
- luego alteras la **tabla** `public.sec_'||nombretabla||'`
- finalmente quieres asignar por defecto el valor de `NEXTVAL ("public"."sec_' || nombretabla||'")`

eso no va funcionar. Le estás diciendo que use NEXTVAL sobre una tabla.

Suponiendo que en realidad quieres asignar por defecto el NEXTVAL de `mod_riestadistica.sec_'||nombretabla||'_seq` la segunda sentencia debiese contener:

```
DEFAULT NEXTVAL (''"mod_riestadistica"."sec_' || nombretabla||'_seq"'')
```

Y con eso puedes referenciar secuencias de otros schemas. Al ejecutar eso, en la definición de la tabla creada verías que el valor por defecto (suponiendo que la tabla se llama **tablaprueba**) es:

```
nextval('mod_riestadistica.sec_tablaprueba_seq'::regclass)
```